# Identify Previously Registered Users (Android/Java)

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction with this. I have an SQL Lite database set up that allows the user to add their account details. It also allows to edit the account details when returning to the application.

I really want the application to identify whether the user has previously added an account or is a new user. If they are a new user it will display a register button. If it is a returning user it will forward them onto the main menu activity.

I will attach some code as an example.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Register.java

```
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.EditText;
   import android.widget.Toast;

   public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
}

public void btnCreate(View view) {

    SQLHelper sqlHelper = new SQLHelper(this);

    EditText addName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameText);
    EditText edtEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameEmail);
    EditText edtNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editNumber);
    EditText edtAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editAge);
    EditText edtNurse = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editNurse);

    sqlHelper.insert(addName.getText().toString(), edtEmail.getText().toString(), Integer.parseInt(edtNumber.getText().toString()), Integer.parseInt(edtAge.getText().toString()), edtNurse.getText().toString());
    Toast.makeText(this, "Account Has Been Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    startActivity(new Intent(Register.this, MainMenu.class));
}
   }
```

Welcome.java:

```
   package my.example.com.mymedicare;

   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.View;

   public class Welcome extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
    };


public void btnRegister(View view) {

    startActivity(new Intent(Welcome.this, Register.class));
}

public void btnContinue(View view) {

    startActivity(new Intent(Welcome.this, MainMenu.class));
}


   }
```

Comment: save the registered state to SharedPreferences and check the SharedPreferences on app start up to see if you should display the register or not. or you could check the sqlite database to see if a table has been created and use that to determine whether or not the user has registered

Comment: How would i be able to check the database if the table has already been created with that specific users details?